# Issue with counting multiple words in a string

Tags: vb.net

I need some help finding out how to deal with this problem. The code I'm trying to make takes two user-inputted strings, open/searches a txt file, and counts how many times those two strings are mentioned.

With the code I have so far, it does not take into account multiple strings in a single line. For ex. if  I am searching for "Bob" and one line has two instances of Bob, it would only count one instance. This is very puzzling and any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
 Dim inFile As IO.StreamReader
    Dim String1 As String
    Dim Count1 As Integer
    Dim Count2 As Integer
    Dim Text1 As String = TextBox1.Text.ToUpper
    Dim Text2 As String = TextBox2.Text.ToUpper

    String1.Text = ""
    String2.Text = ""

    If IO.File.Exists("C:\names.txt") Then
        inFile = IO.File.OpenText("C:\names.txt")

        While Not inFile.EndOfStream
            String1 = inFile.ReadLine()

            If String1.ToUpper.Contains(Text1) Then
                Count1 += 1
                If String1.ToUpper.Contains(Text2) Then
                    Count2 += 1
                End If
            End If
        End While
        inFile.Close()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("xx",
                        "xx",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End If


    String1.Text = Count1.ToString
    String2.Text = Count2.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: One problem here is that Contains goes left to right from begining of the string, repeating the same IF will not catch the 2nd occurence (if exists). I suggest you use another function such as IndexOf: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y7ddk24.aspx

Comment: I have tried using IndexOf but the outputted count ended up being far greater than the real number. The code I modified looks like 'If String1.ToUpper.IndexOf(Text1) then' . I have also tried using substrings but that also gives out errors. I might have done it wrong, though...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example close to your case (you may adapt it using your variable names). Also, it is a good practice to do the logic in a separate Method/Function and call it from your main loop.

```
    Dim inputS, upperS,searchArg, upperSearchArg AS String
    Dim pos,howMany As Integer
    pos=0 'initialize the start position
    howMany=0
    searchArg="Bob " 'use a trailing space if you don't want to find bobby
    upperSearchArg=searchArg.ToUpper()
    inputS="Andrew and Bob are nice but bob is weird some times:"
    upperS=inputS.ToUpper()
    Do      
        pos=upperS.IndexOf(upperSearchArg,pos) 'here we use a variable start position
        if (pos > -1) 
            Console.WriteLine("Found one occurence at:" + pos.ToString())
            howMany=howMany+1
            pos=pos+1 'change the start position
        else
            'pos is -1 here
            exit do
        End if
    Loop
    Console.WriteLine("Total Founds:"+howMany.toString())
```

Note that the above code would not locate "Bob " in a string that ends with "Bob" without the trailing blank. This should be simple to fix.

There are other methods to use to match multiple strings, e.g using LINQ.